# Node cannot find module

Tags: node.js

I had old node version and I delete it. And I install new node version (6.9.5).

But I can't use node because if I try

```
npm install
```

I get error

```
cannot find module 'bl'
```

Comment: Because its looking for package called `bl` version which does not have in npm repo try changing its version in package.json to latest (1.2.0 is latest set in package.json) here is link https://www.npmjs.com/package/bl

Comment: I have a feeling that your `npm` is broken. Try `https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#if-your-npm-is-broken`. And also if you are using windows machine try reinstalling `node` from the official website.